# If $g(x) \in K[x]$, the $g(\alpha)=0$ if and only if $f(x)|g(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

> Let $K $ a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, $\alpha$ a complexe number which
>   is algebraic on $K$ and $f(x) \in K[x]$ the minimal polynomial of
>   $\alpha$ on $K$. If $g(x) \in K[x]$, the $g(\alpha)=0$ if and only if
>   $f(x)|g(x)$

I know that as $f$ is minimal, then $deg(f) \leq deg(g)$ and I think I can use the simple Euclidean division.

Is anyone could give me a hint for the sufficient condition (i.e. $\implies$)? Could we show the principle of descent to infinity with the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: Both are right. I'll stop to do that now. It's just a way that I found when I did not answer quickly enough.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g(x) = f(x)q(x) + m(x)$ by Euclidean division $deg(m) < deg (f)$.

Calculate in $\alpha$, you get:

$0 = g(\alpha) = f(\alpha)q(\alpha) + m(\alpha) = 0 + m(\alpha) = m(\alpha)$

thus $m(x)$ is a new polynomial in $K[x]$ which has $\alpha$ as root and degree strictly lower than $f$. Absurd. Thus $m(x) \equiv 0$.